# How to sum amplitudes only without distorting the signal?

Tags: fft, audio, python, phase

I do audio signal processing using Python (scipy, numpy etc.) I'm trying to "mix" 2 audio signals in a way that reduces phase canceling as much as possible. So I do an FFT of the 2 signals, add the amplitudes only and keep the phases of the 1st signal then invert back to signal (waveform). It actually works pretty well but I get noise. My question is: is there a way to do this without getting noise ?

Jdip asked for the code so here it is. Note that the 2 audio files to mix should be named Mix audio 1.wav and Mix audio 2.wav

```
# IMPORT LIBRARIES
from sys import exit
import scipy.fft
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import librosa
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np ; np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf) # print lists entirely

# IMPORT AUDIO
_file1 = 'Mix audio 1.wav'
_signal1, _sample_rate = librosa.load(_file1, sr=None, res_type='scipy', mono=True) # import/convert audio
_duration = len(_signal1) / _sample_rate # audio file duration
_N = _signal1.size
print(f"Duration: {len(_signal1) / _sample_rate}s ; Channels: {len(_signal1.shape)} ; Sample rate: {_sample_rate} ; Signal length: {len(_signal1)} ; Time step: {1000/_sample_rate}ms")
_file2 = 'Mix audio 2.wav'
_signal2, _sample_rate = librosa.load(_file2, sr=None, res_type='scipy', mono=True) # import/convert audio
_duration = len(_signal2) / _sample_rate # audio file duration
print(f"Duration: {len(_signal2) / _sample_rate}s ; Channels: {len(_signal2.shape)} ; Sample rate: {_sample_rate} ; Signal length: {len(_signal2)} ; Time step: {1000/_sample_rate}ms")

# Amplitude Mixing

_FFT1 = scipy.fft.fft(_signal1)[:_N//2] # rect. coord. of vectors per freq (complex nb), removes mirror values
_FFT2 = scipy.fft.fft(_signal2)[:_N//2] # rect. coord. of vectors per freq (complex nb), removes mirror values
_AmpsMix = np.abs(_FFT1) + np.abs(_FFT2) # raw amp summing

_phases = np.angle(_FFT1) # phase per freq (angle of vectors, polar)

_FFTmix = _AmpsMix*np.exp(1j*_phases) # polar back to rectangular
_signalMix = scipy.fft.irfft(_FFTmix) # inverse FFT back to waveform

#sd.play(_signalMix, _sample_rate) ; sd.wait() # play _signal array as sound

# WAVEFORM PLOT
_signal = _signalMix
_time = np.linspace(0, _duration, len(_signal)) # build time list
_Time_min, _Time_max = (0, _duration) ; _Amp_min, _Amp_max = (-1, 1)
_Waveform_plot = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10)) ; plt.grid(axis='both')
plt.plot(_time, _signal, ':', label="signal")
plt.xlabel('Time (s)') ; plt.ylabel('Signal (-1/+1)')
plt.xlim(_Time_min, _Time_max) ; plt.ylim(_Amp_min, _Amp_max) # TIME range ; AMP range
plt.xticks(ticks=np.linspace(plt.xlim()[0], plt.xlim()[1], 11))
plt.yticks(ticks=np.linspace(plt.ylim()[0], plt.ylim()[1], 21))
_Waveform_plot.show()

exit()
```

Thanks, cheers :)  Guillaume

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: you would only get significant cancellation if the two signals are fairly correlated. What's the nature (or root cause) of the correlation ?

Comment: Sure Jdip, I've added the code to my question.

Comment: Hilmar, the signals are correlated because they are audio recording of one note of an instrument played at different dynamics so their waveforms are very similar and mixing causes comb filtering effects. I'm looking for a spectral way to solve this issue rather than just delaying one of the 2 signals (usual method).